# Compile libIEC61850 with mingw and eclipse fails

Tags: mingw

Hy i have installed mingw and eclipse-cdt.
I am trying to compile the Project libiec61850:[http://libiec61850.com/..](http://libiec61850.com/libiec61850/documentation/building-the-library/)

I installed cmake from [here](http://www.cmake.org/files/v3.0/cmake-3.0.2-win32-x86.exe)

After I extracted the libiec61850 I created a new folder build-mingw and started the following command:
cmake .. -G"Eclipse CDT4 - MinGW Makefiles"
the command ends with:
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: E:/libiec61850-0.8.0/build-mingw

After that i imported the folder build-mingw into eclipse(with out copy the files to my workspace)
When i start the make target : all it fails
Can some one tell me what i did wrong?
Here is the error line from CDT:

```
17:33:43 **** Build of project libiec61850@build-mingw ****
"C:\\MinGW\\bin\\mingw32-make.exe" all 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -HE:\libiec61850-0.8.0 -BE:\libiec61850-0.8.0\build-mingw --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_start E:\libiec61850-0.8.0\build-mingw\CMakeFiles E:\libiec61850-0.8.0\build-mingw\CMakeFiles\progress.marks
C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 all
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'E:/libiec61850-0.8.0/build-mingw'
C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make -f src\CMakeFiles\iec61850.dir\build.make src/CMakeFiles/iec61850.dir/depend
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'E:/libiec61850-0.8.0/build-mingw'
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_depends "MinGW Makefiles" E:\libiec61850-0.8.0 E:\libiec61850-0.8.0\src E:\libiec61850-0.8.0\build-mingw E:\libiec61850-0.8.0\build-mingw\src E:\libiec61850-0.8.0\build-mingw\src\CMakeFiles\iec61850.dir\DependInfo.cmake --color=
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'E:/libiec61850-0.8.0/build-mingw'
C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make -f src\CMakeFiles\iec61850.dir\build.make src/CMakeFiles/iec61850.dir/build
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'E:/libiec61850-0.8.0/build-mingw'
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_report E:\libiec61850-0.8.0\build-mingw\CMakeFiles 
[  0%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/iec61850.dir/common/string_map.c.obj
cd /d E:\libiec61850-0.8.0\build-mingw\src && C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe   -DEXCLUDE_ETHERNET_WINDOWS @CMakeFiles/iec61850.dir/includes_CXX.rsp   -o CMakeFiles\iec61850.dir\common\string_map.c.obj -c E:\libiec61850-0.8.0\src\common\string_map.c
src\CMakeFiles\iec61850.dir\build.make:54: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/iec61850.dir/common/string_map.c.obj' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/iec61850.dir/common/string_map.c.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'E:/libiec61850-0.8.0/build-mingw'
mingw32-make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/iec61850.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:1325: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/iec61850.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'E:/libiec61850-0.8.0/build-mingw'
Makefile:116: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

Comment: I found a solution to build it. I had to add the path to the msys bin folder to path and then i simply extracted the Project and imported it to eclipse by using the "Existing Code as Makefile Project" Import. Now you just have to run the all target of the makefile in the project root and you'll get the library as a .a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to build it. I had to add the path to the msys bin folder to path and then i simply extracted the Project and imported it to eclipse by using the "Existing Code as Makefile Project" Import. Now you just have to run the all target of the makefile in the project root and you'll get the library as a .a file.

Comment: ...funny thing that if you search for "iec61850" on Stackoverflow you get ~7 questions from which one was asked/answered by a coworker of mine, @maxbit89 ;)